# Compare Folders, Create Archive of Differences

Tags: compare, diff, tar

I have folder A and folder B

**Folder A** contains approx 100 files all text, js, php, bash etc. They are stored in the root of the folder and sub folders and further sub folders within folder A.

**Folder B** is a copy of Folder A, but some of the files have been updated.

Is there any way I can compare A to B and create a tar.gz file containing only the files that have changed in **Folder B**

I would need to keep the folder structure intact when the tar.gz is created.

Currently I use WinMerge to check for differences, but I'm happy to look at any windows or Linux application/commands that will help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line excludes files that are only in one or the other, but creates the tar.gz file that you want.

```
diff -rq folderA folderB | grep -v "^Only in" | sed "s/^.*and folderB/folderB/g" | sed "s/ differ//g" | tar czf output.tar.gz -T -
```

Broken down it goes:

```
dif -rq folderA folderB
```

Do a recursive diff between these folders, be quiet about it - only output the file names.

```
| grep -v "^Only in"
```

Exclude output lines that indicate one file is only in one of the folders. I'm assuming from your description this isn't an issue for you, but the two folders I was playing with were a bit dirty.

```
| sed "s/^.*and folderB/folderB/g"
```

Discard the first bit of the output up until it says " and " and then the name of the second folder.  This actually takes away the second folder name as well, but then replaces it back in

```
| sed "s/ differ//g"
```

Discard the end bit of the diff output.

```
| tar czf output.tar.gz -T -
```

Tell tar to do the thing.  `c` == create a tar file `z` means compress it (zip) `f` means the filename is coming shortly.  `output.tar.gz` is your output file `-T` means "get the filenames from the file I'm about to tell you"  the final `-` means "use stdin instead"

I suggest you build this up yourself in the individual steps so you can see how it is constructed, and what the output of each step is like.

Comment: Thanks this works, but the resulting the tar.gz file has folderB as the first folder within the file. Is it possible to have it only save the files and subfolder structure. eg: one level in to folderB ?

Comment: Running the command in folderB, updating the paths used and excluding the output.tar.gz seems to work. `diff -rq ../folderA . | grep -v "^Only in" | sed "s/^.*and .\///g" | sed "s/ differ//g" | tar czf output.tar.gz --exclude=*.tar.gz -T -
`